# Doesn't add all elements that are not in dictionary values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm iterating over the list and supposedly add element to dictionary that doesn't occur in dictionary as value, therefore I would expect output:

```
{'key': 1, 'key2': 3, 'key3': 2, 'key4':4, 'key5':5}
```

Code:

```
di = {'key':1, 'key2':4}

li=[1,1,1,2,4,3,5]

b = sum(1 for key in di if key.startswith('key')) # check how many keys starts with 'key'

for i in li:                #if element of list is not in dictionary key values 
    if i not in di.values():  #add it as value to 'key+b+1'
        di[f'key{b+1}']= i
```

But the ouput I'm getting:

```
{'key': 1, 'key2': 4, 'key3': 5}
```

So as I see despite I'm telling Python to check elements in dict.values he's checking also keys or items.

Comment: Oh right, missed that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that after you add a new key to di, you don't increment the count b.
Use the following to solve your problem:

```
for i in li:                #if element of list is not in dictionary key values 
    if i not in di.values():  #add it as value to 'key+b+1'
        di[f'key{b+1}']= i
        b += 1
```

Which produces:

```
{'key': 1, 'key2': 4, 'key3': 2, 'key4': 3, 'key5': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @itprorh66 mentioned. You need to increment `b` as you're adding keys.

Here's an alternate approach:

```
# Original dict
di = {'key': 1, 'key2': 4}
# list of values to add
li = [1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
# start key number
b = sum(1 for key in di if key.startswith('key')) + 1
# list of values to add
values = [i for i in set(li) if i not in di.values()]
# list of keys to add
keys = [f'key{i}' for i in range(b, b + len(values))]
# add them to the dict
di.update(zip(keys, values))
```